# Как сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал на голосовые сообщения пользователей?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

Я использую библиотку aiogram и пишу бота тг для беседы. Мне нужно сделать функционал, если пользовател отвечает боту голосовым сообщением, тоесть делает ответ на любое сообщение бота, обязательно голосовым сообщением. После ответа голосовым сообщением, бот должен посылать любое сообщение, например "да" или "нет". Есть идеи как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types='voice')
async def voice_message(message: types.Message):
    if(message.voice):
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "This is voice")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]